# Creating a list from a Scipy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

This is my first post and I'm still a Python and Scipy newcomer, so go easy on me! I'm trying to convert an Nx1 matrix into a python list. Say I have some 3x1 matrix

`x = scipy.matrix([1,2,3]).transpose()`

My aim is to create a list, y, from x so that

`y = [1, 2, 3]`

I've tried using the `tolist()` method, but it returns `[[1], [2], [3]]`, which isn't the result that I'm after. The best i can do is this

```
y = [xi for xi in x.flat]
```

but it's a bit cumbersome, and I'm not sure if there's an easier way to achieve the same result. Like I said, I'm still coming to grips with Python and Scipy...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A question for your question

While Sven and Navi have answered your question on how to convert

```
x = scipy.matrix([1,2,3]).transpose()
```

into a list, I'll ask a question before answering:

- Why are you using an Nx1 matrix instead of an array?

### Using array instead of matrix

If you look at the Numpy for Matlab Users wiki/documentation page, section 3 discusses [*'array' or 'matrix'? Which should I use?*](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935). The short answer is that you should use array.

One of the advantages of using an array is that:

> You can treat rank-1 arrays as either row or column vectors. dot(A,v) treats v as a column vector, while dot(v,A) treats v as a row vector. This can save you having to type a lot of transposes.

Also, as stated in the [Numpy Reference Documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.classes.html#matrix-objects), "Matrix objects are always two-dimensional." This is why `x.tolist()` returned a nested list of `[[1], [2], [3]]` for you.

Since you want an Nx1 object, I'd recommend using array as follows:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> x = scipy.array([1,2,3])
>>> x
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> y = x.tolist()     // That's it. A clean, succinct conversion to a list.
>>> y
[1, 2, 3]
```

### If you really want to use matrix

If for some reason you truly need/want to use a matrix instead of an array, here's what I would do:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> x = scipy.matrix([1,2,3]).transpose()
>>> x
matrix([[1],
        [2],
        [3]])
>>> y = x.T.tolist()[0]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3]
```

In words, the `x.T.tolist()[0]` will:

1. Transpose the x matrix using the `.T` attribute
2. Convert the transposed matrix into a nested list using `.tolist()`
3. Grab the first element of the nested listed using `[0]`

Comment: OK thanks, I see what you're saying - it does make it a lot cleaner to use an array instead. To answer your question: I chose matrix over array because I want to do some simple linear algebra, and I thought it would be easier to work with types that are less generalised. In particular, the * operator does proper matrix multiplication instead of elementwise multiplication (I know I can use multiply(), but I thought it would've been more convenient)

Comment: Using matrix for linear algebra is more convenient, since A*B is matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
x.ravel().tolist()[0]
```

or

```
scipy.array(x).ravel().tolist()
```

Comment: Ok great, that seems to work thanks. I notice that if I replace ravel() with flatten(), it gives me the same result too...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there use the flatten function http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

Comment: Yip, if I do scipy.array(x).flatten().tolist(), it gives me the desired list; thanks.